# Can a good decree on Rosh Hashanah be rescinded?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, repentance-teshuvah

If someone was decreed for the good on Rosh Hashanah and afterwards sinned (possibly say with nivul peh) can the good decree be rescinded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. See Rosh Hashanah 17b:

> עתים לרעה כיצד הרי שהיו ישראל צדיקים גמורין בר"ה ופסקו עליהן גשמים מרובין לסוף חזרו בהן לפחות מהן אי אפשר שכבר נגזרה גזרה אלא הקב"ה מורידן שלא בזמנן על הארץ שאינה צריכה להן
>   Sometimes for bad, how so? Consider if Yisrael were completely righteous on Rosh Hashanah, and a lot of rain was allotted to them. They then reverted [to wickedness]. To reduce the rain isn’t possible, since the decree was already decreed. Rather, Hashem will cause the rain to fall when it’s not appropriate on land which doesn’t need it.

Note that the Gemara there says that the opposite case depends on the circumstances of the decree. Minimal rainfall can still be given beneficially, but sometimes bad decrees are torn up entirely.

Comment: if you keep reading you’ll see this is only concerning a community, not an individual

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/100415).